# How do I set up a room database with an array of data class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I need to set up a room database for offline caching. I need it to be in this format.

```
class House : ArrayList<HouseItem>()

data class HouseItem(
val actor: String,
val house: String,
val image: String,
val name: String )
```

I need it so i can retrieve House the house type and put it into

```
    var houseLiveData : MutableLiveData<House>  = MutableLiveData()
```

Comment: *I need it so I can retrieve House the house type*, Do you want to insert and retrieve a list of `HouseItem` from Room database?

Comment: why dont you just make var houseLiveData : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HouseItem>>  = MutableLiveData()

Answer (score 0):

As a column in a table MUST be a single type not an array/list/collection etc then you need an entity that uses a single type.

For that class to be a table then the Room `@Entity` annotation is used.

So you could have a class such as :-

```
@Entity
data class AltHouseEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val houses: House
)
```

However, as Room can only store specific limited object types,**House** is NOT one of them, then you need to have **TypeConvereters** to convert a **House** to one of the types that can be stored.  The most apt type would probably be a String and that String would probably be JSON String.

To accompany the above class you would have another class where the conversion functions/methods are defined/coded.

You require 2 methods per Object. One, for adding/updating data, to allow conversion from the Object to the type being stored and another, for extracting data, to convert from the stored type to the Object.

Such functions need to be annotated with `@TypeConverter`, the class(es) need to be defined via `@TypeConverters` annotation (**NOTE the spelling difference between the two annotations *i.e. one is singular the other is plural*).

So you could have a Class such as :-

```
class HouseConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun convertFromHouseToJSONString(houseToConvert: House): String {
        return Gson().toJson(houseToConvert)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun convertFromJSOnStringToHouse(jsonToConvert: String): House {
        return Gson().fromJson(jsonToConvert, House::class.java)
    }
}
```

- again note the singular `@TypeConverter` and not `@TypeConverters`

Last you need to use the `@TypeConverters` (plural) annotation to define the TypeConverter classes. The scope of the TypeConverter classes is determined by where the `@TypeConverters` annotation is placed.

If it is placed at the @Database/Database level then the scope of the TypeConverters is for the entire database. If at the @Entity level then  the scope is for that class, if at the field/variable level then the scope is for that field.

- @TypeConvereters can also be coded within DAO classes. See [TypeConverters](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/TypeConverters) for comprehensive information.

The @Database scope is fine for many situations so the class for the Database, that includes the `@Database` annotation, to include the above could be :-

```
@Database(entities = [AltHouseEntity::class],version = 1)
@TypeConverters(HouseConverters::class)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() { ....
```

- i.e.:-

  - The **AltHouseEntity** class is specified as a table via the entities property of the @Database annotation.
  - The **HouseConverters** class is defined at the @Database/Database level so has scope throughout the database.

Using the above approach if a AltHouseEntity is defined, as an example, using :-

```
    val ahouse1 = AltHouseEntity(houses = House())
    ahouse1.houses.addAll(
        listOf(
            HouseItem(
                actor = "Fred",
                house = "house1",
                image = "theimageforItem1",
                name = "Item1"
            ),
            HouseItem(
                actor = "Mary",
                house = "house1",
                image = "theimageforItem2",
                name = "Item2"
            )
        )
    )
```

Then it is stored in the AltHouseEntity table as :-

[image]

You just then need a suitable @Query to extract the appropriate data.